# Convert events to Redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Currently, I'm working on a project using events to update other components that listen to these events and trying to convert these events to Redux actions.

An example when the user login there are components listen to this event and call an API to update its state, The events were firing based on if the component exists or not so with Redux I have to check if the props got changed or not inside the component using `componentWillupdate` and from there I call the API.

I need to know if this is the best solution for doing things similar or there is another plugin I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor the code removing the emit/listen to event pattern to something more close to Redux's architecture.

The components that emit events should call action creators. These action creators can call REST  API or do other async stuff (using, for example, [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)) and generate zero, one or more actions to update Redux's state.

On the other end, the components that listen to events have to receive in input the new data from Redux's state and update accordingly. A simple component should change its behavior when its props change, in other words, when its state change. In this case, the component's state is a subset of data stored inside Redux and updated by the reducers when new actions are dispatched.